# How to implement python style indentation in yacc or bison?

Tags: bison, yacc, cpython

I have been trying to implement python style indentation in my bison grammar, some insights or ideas to that implementation would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is usually to have the lexer track the indentation level and insert INDENT/UNINDENT tokens into the token stream appropriately.  Here's some flex code I have to do that:

```
%x LINESTART
%s NORMAL
%{
static std::stack<int> indent;
static int indent_depth(const char *);
%}

%%

<INITIAL>.*|\n          { yyless(0); BEGIN(LINESTART); indent.push(0); }
<LINESTART>[ \t]*       { int depth = indent_depth(yytext);
                          if (depth < indent.top()) {
                              indent.pop();
                              yyless(0);
                              return UNINDENT; }
                          BEGIN(NORMAL);
                          if (depth > indent.top()) {
                              indent.push(depth);
                              return INDENT; } }
<LINESTART>.            { yyless(0);
                          if (indent.top() > 0) {
                              indent.pop();
                              return UNINDENT; }
                          BEGIN(NORMAL); }
<LINESTART><<EOF>>      { if (indent.top() > 0) {
                              indent.pop();
                              return UNINDENT; }
                          BEGIN(NORMAL); }
<LINESTART>[ \t]*\n     { lineno++; }
<LINESTART>[ \t]*#.*\n  { lineno++; }
[[({]                   { parens++; return *yytext; }
[])}]                   { if (--parens < 0) parens = 0;
                          return *yytext; }
\n                      { lineno++;
                          if (parens == 0) BEGIN(LINESTART); }
```

This code is somewhat tricky with special cases -- for example, you need to ignore blank lines and lines with just comments, and you probably also want to ignore indentation within unbalanced parenthesis (which the above does).